# Parameter of a PUT method always null

Tags: c#, api, web-services, .net-core

here I meet for some time a problem with a method PUT. When I test this method locally everything works fine, but as soon as I publish it on my server the parameter is null. Below is an excerpt from the method.

My API is coded in .net Core 2.0 and the server is under Windows server 2016.

```
[HttpPut]
public JsonResult Update([FromBody]MyModel data)
{
    Logger.Info("Initialisation de l'API d'update structure");
    JsonResult respFormat;
    if (data != null)
    {
        //TODO Update structure
        var respFormat = new JsonResult("Update OK");
        respFormat.StatusCode = StatusCodes.Status200OK;
        return respFormat;
    }
    else
    {
        var respFormat = new JsonResult("MyModel null");
        respFormat.StatusCode = StatusCodes.Status404NotFound;
        return respFormat;
    }
}
```

My model.

```
public class MyModel{
    public int IdStructure {get;set;}
    public int NameStructure {get;set;}
    ...
}
```

I tried to publish my API on another server but the problem is the same.

If someone has already cared and has found a solution I am interested. Thank you in advance.

Comment: My first reaction is "do you do the exact same call locally and on-server? Double check that.

Comment: For both I tested through Swagger and Postman. The past parameters were the same.

Comment: @Space Any configuration changes that you might be missing when you are publishing to the server?

Comment: Besides checking config like @Space says, are you sure you really have updated the server when you think you do? _Please do not mistake me for being rude_; I don't know what you have tried and where in the debugging process you are. I base my input on what I would have wanted someone to ask med if I was in your spot.